# Did any sect reject animal sacrifice from the time of its founding?

Tags: animals, sects, sacrifice

I believe Sankara, Ramanuja et al condoned the idea of animal sacrifice.  I think Ramanuja says the sacrificed animal may feel some pain but it would reach a higher state after being sacrificed.

If you know Tamil, there is a u-tube video of a Vaishnavite teacher who says the sacrificed animal may look forward to being reborn as a human in a Vaishnavite household.

(1) Was any sect against it from the time of its founding?

(2) Would rejecting animal sacrifice make a sect "veda-viruddha" since animal sacrifice is very much part of Rig Veda?

Comment: Is it condoned or condemned? Please clarify and give references

Comment: "it is because of mistranslation some people seems that animal sacrifice is in Vedas" - @rickross - it is the colosal ambiguity of Sanskrit that such contrived readings of scripture are possible (like Madhwa claiming to read "atat twam asi"

Comment: Is it condemned ? No. Does not following it mean you are against Vedas ? No.

Comment: "Would rejecting animal sacrifice make a sect "veda-viruddha" since animal sacrifice is very much part of Rig Veda?" To me, Yes! For example whole Buddhism is "Veda Viruddha". But this question is completely opinion based.

Comment: Atharva Veda 1.4.1, Atharva Veda 3.16.6, Atharva Veda 5.27.8, Rigveda 3.10.7, Rigveda 3.16.6, Rigveda 4.6.1, Rigveda 5.49.4, Rigveda 1.74.4 Yajurveda 1.24, Yajurveda 3.11 etc.in all these places Vedas are called adhwar then how animal sacrifice is right? Who could understand Vedas better than Krishna. Lord Krishna in Srimad Bhagvatam 11.21.30 says, “People who find enjoyment in violence, out of wickedness and for gratification of their pleasure they slaughter animals, offer the meat in Yajan’s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Veera Saivism rejected animal sacrifice.

> #### Contemplative Practices in Śaivism
>
> Swami Tadananda
>
> Vīraśaiva is a vibrant monotheistic faith, particularly prominent in its homeland—Karnataka. It was made popular by the Sri Basaveshvara (1105-67). The Vīraśaiva movement championed the cause of the downtrodden and evolved as a revolt against a system which fostered social inequality. Going against the way of the times, **it rejected Vedic authority**, caste hierarchy, the system of four stages of life, and veneration of a multiplicity of gods; the concepts of karmic bondage, existence of inner worlds, and the duality of God and soul; temple worship, ritualistic priest-craft, **animal sacrifice**, and the traditions of ritual purity-pollution.
>
> ([Prabuddha Bharata, January, 2007](https://advaitaashrama.org/pb/2007/012007.pdf))

It also rejected Vedic authority, as mentioned above.

Comment: Veershaiv don't reject animal sacrifice. Śrīpati Paṇḍitārādhya in his Srikara bhasya accept/support animal sacrifice. --> https://archive.org/details/TheSrikaraBhashyaOfSripatiPanditacharyaVol.IIC.HayavadanaRao/page/n345/mode/2up?view=theater

Answer (score 3):

It is *Aryasamaj* they clearly reject the animal sacrifice. Maharishi Dayanand Saraswati (Founder of Aryasamaj) wrote in [Satyarth Prakash chapter 11 page 339](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/chaptereleven.htm#4)

> Now look at the trickery of these stupid popes that **whatever is considered to be highly sinful and opposed to the Veda is regarded as virtuous by the Vaama Margis. The use of meat,** wine, fish, delicious eatables, such as various kinds of cakes, and copulation are considered as means of attaining salvation.

Comment: Your blockquote is listed under "The sect of Vaama Margis" so Dayananda Saraswati is talking about Vaama Margis and expressing his displeasure about their ways, doesn't necessarily mean Arya Samaj does everything opposite of Vaama Margis.

Comment: @sv. Vaama margis are called **stupid Pope's** in Satyarth Prakash. Rishi Dayanand criticized them a lot. And many YouTubers of Aryasamaj reject the animal sacrifice.

Comment: I think you didn't follow my previous comment. You need to cite Arya Samajis saying something about themselves. Not criticism of some xyz sect.

Comment: @sv. It is a common thing. If someone is opposing something it means that they are not in their favour. Read what is written. **highly sinful and opposed to the Veda is regarded as virtuous by the Vaama Margis** . It clarifies that as per Arya samajis, animal sacrifice is against Vedas.

Comment: If you know the difference between pratyaksha & anumana, that's difference between 'Arya Samajis saying something about themselves' and the reference you cited.

Comment: @sv. And if you have some common sense than you will realise what I am saying.